# Strip CMS Signature from file (using openssl?)

Tags: openssl, digital-signature, cms

I have a lot of binary files that contain some data that is signed using CMS.

The files have the form:

```
$ openssl cms -inform DER -in test.cms -cmsout -print
CMS_ContentInfo: 
  contentType: pkcs7-signedData (1.2.840.113549.1.7.2)
  d.signedData: 
    version: 3
    digestAlgorithms:
        algorithm: sha256 (2.16.840.1.101.3.4.2.1)
        parameter: <ABSENT>
    encapContentInfo: 
      eContentType: pkcs7-data (1.2.840.113549.1.7.1)
      eContent: 
        0000 - 21 3c 61 72 63 68 3e 0a-64 65 62 69 61 6e 2d   !<arch>.debian-
        000f - 62 69 6e 61 72 79 2f 20-20 XX XX XX XX XX XX   binary/  XXXXXX
        […]
     10d82ab - d7 00 28 00 00                                 ..(..
    certificates:
      <ABSENT>
    crls:
      <ABSENT>
    signerInfos:
        version: 3
        d.subjectKeyIdentifier: 
          0000 - (DATA REMOVED FOR PRIVACY REASONS)
          000f - (DATA REMOVED FOR PRIVACY REASONS)
        digestAlgorithm: 
          algorithm: sha256 (2.16.840.1.101.3.4.2.1)
          parameter: <ABSENT>
        signedAttrs:
            object: contentType (1.2.840.113549.1.9.3)
            set:
              OBJECT:pkcs7-data (1.2.840.113549.1.7.1)

            object: signingTime (1.2.840.113549.1.9.5)
            set:
              UTCTIME: (SOMETIME) 2021 GMT

            object: messageDigest (1.2.840.113549.1.9.4)
            set:
              OCTET STRING:
                0000 - (DATA REMOVED FOR PRIVACY REASONS)
                000d - (DATA REMOVED FOR PRIVACY REASONS)
                001a - (DATA REMOVED FOR PRIVACY REASONS)
        signatureAlgorithm: 
          algorithm: ecdsa-with-SHA256 (1.2.840.10045.4.3.2)
          parameter: <ABSENT>
        signature: 
          0000 - (DATA REMOVED FOR PRIVACY REASONS)
          000f - (DATA REMOVED FOR PRIVACY REASONS)
          001e - (DATA REMOVED FOR PRIVACY REASONS)
          002d - (DATA REMOVED FOR PRIVACY REASONS)
          003c - (DATA REMOVED FOR PRIVACY REASONS)
        unsignedAttrs:
          <ABSENT>
```

I'm currently not interested in the signature. Is there an elegant way to strip it?
I can build work-around code that tries to analyze the output above, `grep` in the file and `dd` parts of it but this seems rather ugly.

Comment: `openssl cms -in file -inform der -verify -nosigs -noverify -out newfile` (oxymoronic though it appears)

Answer (score 1):

```
openssl cms -inform DER -in (file_with_signature) -cmsout -print | sed -n '/eContent/,/certificates/p' | grep -v eContent | grep -v certificates | awk -F' ' '{print $3$4$5$6$7$8$9$10$11$12$13$14$15$16}' | sed 's/-//' | xxd -r -p > (file_without_signature)
```

Starting with your command, and piping through things:

1. `sed -n '/eContent/,/certificates/p'` prints only the section of the output that contains the original binary file,
2. `grep -v eContent` removes the line that says `eContent`,
3. `grep -v certificates` removes the line that says `certificates`,
4. `awk -F' ' '{print $3$4$5$6$7$8$9$10$11$12$13$14$15$16}'` prints only the section containing the hexadecimal corresponding to the original binary file content,
5. `sed 's/-//'` removes the dash in the binary content (who knows why THAT is in there, whatever), and finally,
6. `xxd -r -p` reverts the hexadecimal output to binary.

The `> (file_without_signature)` part sends the output to a new file, that contains only the original binary, without the signature.

Note that your `(file_without_signature)` should be named with a recognizable file extension (probably, whatever file extension the original binary would have had), and you may need to use `chmod` to change read/write/execute permissions, for the new file to be usable in the way that it was, before it was signed.

P.S. - If "elegance" is a concern, you can copy/paste that command into a script and replace `(file_with_signature)` with `$1`, and `(file_without_signature)` with `$2`, for a command that executes like:

```
./script.sh (file_with_signature) (file_without_signature).
```

Or, in the script, use a `for file in /directory/path do` before the command, replace `(file_with_signature)` with `$file`, and `(file_without_signature)` with `$file.orig`, then `done` after the command, to iterate over a whole directory of these things, and create a bunch of `.orig` files, that are the files without the signatures.